# PDO Unbuffered Queries Only When Trying to USE Another Table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to `SELECT` some information from the `information_schema` table through PDO. When performing any other kind of SQL query, everything works fine. However, when trying to run `USE information_schema;` I get the error: `General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.`

In other words, this works:

```
static::rawQuery("SET foreign_key_checks=0;");
```

But this gives me the exception:

```
static::rawQuery("USE `information_schema`;");
```

The methods aren't one after the other - I removed the foreign key statement, and replaced it with the information_schema one.

For reference, the `rawQuery` method:

```
protected static function rawQuery ($query, array $params = null) {
    if ($params === null) {
        $params = [];
    }

    $stmt = static::getPdo()->prepare($query);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $results;
}
```

I do understand, generally, buffering issues in PDO and MySQL. What I can't understand though, is why I *only* get this error when trying to use another database table.

Comment: Can you do something like select `information_schema`.yourcolumn from `information_schema` instead of executing USE `information_schema`;?

Comment: I can, and indeed just did! However, I'm still, let's say, academically curious, if there's an answer to this question.

Comment: There is, but before I write it I need to know whether this solved the problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I wasn't as clear as I could have been - yes, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
USE `information_schema`
```

is already a query and since you attempted to execute another query as well, there were several queries to execute.